# How do you change the spread of the Y axis of pandas box plot?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, boxplot

I am plotting 100 data points for 9 different groups. One group's data points are much larger than all the other groups so when I make a box graph using pandas only that group is shown, while all other groups are smashed to the bottom. Here is what it looks like now: [smushed box plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuqMS.png)

I would like the Y axis to be more spaced out so that I can see the other groups' box graphs. Here is similar data in a scatter plot that has the spacing I am looking for: [well spaced scatter plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDmW4.png)

| [image: now] | [image: need this] |
| --- | --- |
| What I *have* | What is ***need*** |

Here is my code at the moment:

````py
# use ``` to designate a code block in markdown
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

df = pd.read_csv("residues.csv")
df.plot.box()
plt.show()
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want `y` to be log-scaled:

```py
df.plot.box(logy=True)
```

[image: with/without logy]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
boxplot = df.boxplot(column=df.columns)
plt.show()
```

#### Reference

- See the pandas documentation on boxplot: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.boxplot.html

[image]

Comment: This does not solve my problem of only the column with the largest values being shown in the graph. Is there any way to have a more evenly distributed Y axis so that the ranges of all columns can be seen. Like the second image in my original post.